# Expire date column based on a choice (menu) column

Tags: sharepoint-online

Could someone tell me if it's possible to make a column with an expire date, based on a value selected in a choice column.

Example :

**Column A** = date column

**Column B** = choice column with 2 possibilities :

- 3 months
- 5 months

**Column C** = expire date column

What I would like to do :

If column A is 06/03/2021, and that I select 3 months in column B, column C becomes 09/03/2021.

Thanks for your help

KD

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 30-day months, the formula would be:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ColumnA)),IF(ColumnB="3 months",ColumnA+(3*30),IF(ColumnB="5 months",ColumnA+(5*30),"")),"")
```

[image]

We could calculate Expire Dates using **DATE()** function like:

```
DATE(YEAR([ColumnA]),MONTH([ColumnA])+3,DAY([ColumnA]))
```

However, it would be more complex and need to validate the calculated date.
For example, if we add 3 months to 11/30/2020 (mm-dd-yyyy), need to add 1 year to 2020 to make it 2021 and then also verify the max day in February as it could be 28 or 29.

For more info, please refer to [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))